# How do I find in dataframe value in column B exists in Column A in a dataframe, and if so, replace the value in column B with Column A's value?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe-

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col A': ['A:A', 'A:A', 'B:B', 'C:C', 'D:D', 'E:E', 'F:F', 'F:F', 'G:G', 
'H:H'],
                  'Col B': ['A:A', 'F:F', 'B:B', 'C:C', 'D:D', 'E:E', 'E:E', 'F:F', 'G:G', 
'H:H']},
                  )
```

My end goal is to combine all duplicate values of row A, and find out if that row's value in column *B* exists in Column *A* - if it does, i want to update Column B's value to add that value to it- example below:

| Index | Col A | Col B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | A:A | A:A, F:F, E:E |
| 1 | B:B | B:B |
| 2 | C:C | C:C |
| 3 | D:D | D:D |
| 4 | E:E | E:E |
| 5 | F:F | F:F, E:E |
| 6 | G:G | G:G |
| 7 | H:H | H:H |

I've tried applying a depth first search:

```
visited = set()
def dfs(visited, graph, node):
    if node not in visited:
        print (node)
        visited.add(node)
        for neighbour in graph[node]:
            dfs(visited, graph, neighbour)
```

However, i get a key error when i try that:

```
data = np.array(['A:A', 'B:B', 'C:C', 'D:D', 'E:E', 'F:F', 'G:G', 'H:H'])
ser = {'A:A', 'B:B', 'C:C', 'D:D', 'E:E', 'F:F', 'G:G', 'H:H'}
ser = pd.Series(data)

df = df.groupby(['Col1'])['Col2'].apply(' , '.join).reset_index()
for i in df:
    dfs(visited, df, i)



KeyError: 'A:A'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-66-e47c7e4cac17> in <module>
     26 print(df)
     27 for i in df:
---> 28     dfs(visited, df, i)

<ipython-input-66-e47c7e4cac17> in dfs(visited, graph, node)
     17         visited.add(node)
     18         for neighbour in graph[node]:
---> 19             dfs(visited, graph, neighbour)
     20 
     21 data = np.array(['A:A', 'B:B', 'C:C', 'D:D', 'E:E', 'F:F', 'G:G', 'H:H'])

<ipython-input-66-e47c7e4cac17> in dfs(visited, graph, node)
     16         print (node)
     17         visited.add(node)
---> 18         for neighbour in graph[node]:
     19             dfs(visited, graph, neighbour)
     20
```

Unfortunately, my experience in python is limited-what is the best way to go about getting my goal here?

Answer (score 1):

A short, fast solution would be to group by `A` and then aggregate `B` into a list:

```
new_df = df.groupby('Col A')['Col B'].agg(list).str.join(', ').reset_index()
```

Output:

```
>>> new_df
  Col A     Col B
0   A:A  A:A, F:F
1   B:B       B:B
2   C:C       C:C
3   D:D       D:D
4   E:E       E:E
5   F:F  E:E, F:F
6   G:G       G:G
7   H:H       H:H
```

Comment: I've actually got that! Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to combine the outputs of row 5's Column B into Row 0's Column B. I have an idea, however-could i create a new row if Column B exists in Column A, THEN group and agg it?

Comment: Okay, I'll try to figure that out :) Why, though? It's not obvious to me....

Comment: Mine is not to wonder why, mine is but to do and die :) I was given a very, very long report(two columns only, but a couple thousand items bare minimum) and was told that it needs to be aggregated into this SPECIFIC format.

Comment: Ah, okay, I see :) Are you able to explain why the `E:E` should go to the 0th row?  Should all duplicates in the `B` column go to the 0th row? What's the logic behind that? I need to know...otherwise I can't write up a solution ;)

Comment: Ah, my apologies-the reason E:E should go to the 0th row, is because A:A has a value of F:F in column B. Since F:F in column A has a value of E:E as well as a value of F:F, we want the 0th row to have a value of A:A, E:E and F:F

(One thing i just realized i should have clarified-not EVERYTHING in Column B will exist in Column A. A theoretical I:I could have a column B value of X:X, but X:X may not exist at all in Column A)

Comment: Hmmm...I see. So it's a recursion problem...

Comment: So, `E:E` is in the 0th row of col `B`, because `A -> B -> A`. I'm guessing that the number of times `A -> B` and `B -> A` is arbitrary? i.e. `A -> B -> A -> B -> A` or `A -> B`, etc... (hope you understand what I'm trying to express.)

Comment: Correct, yes-it was specifically described to me as "Keep growing the list, until it doesn't grow anymore." I believe it was mentioned that depth-first search was best, but i haven't been able to get one to work for me for this yet.